# ADSI functions sometimes Not Working?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, active-directory, adsi

i am using c++ WIN32 API,i have ADSI functions

```
    CoInitialize(NULL); 
    LPWSTR pszADsPath=NULL;
    pszADsPath= L"LDAP://CN=hari,CN=Users,DC=jegan,DC=com";
    hr = ADsGetObject(pszADsPath, IID_IADsUser, (void**)&pUser);
```

Sometimes it works fine,but most of the times hr gives **`8007054b`**.

how to resolve it?

Comment: The high part 0x8007 means that the lower part is a Win32 error code.  0x054B = 1355 = "The specified domain either does not exist or could not be contacted."  Perhaps you're having communications problems to the domain controller?

Comment: @ Harry : i know it,mr harry.which scenarios this problem is occured.because at the same time using ldap functions connecting to AD & works fine,ADSI only make a problem.